# Which HTML tag do I use for bash command line input?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Say I'm writing an article

```
<p>If you want to check your total memory, run the following command

<pre>$ free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             25            0         25           0           0          24
Swap:             2           0           2</pre>
```

`$ free -g` is the bash input, and the text below is its output.

I would like to style the input and output properly. Although I can use `<div>`, I don't think it's sematic enough.

It looks like [<kbd>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element) is more for keys on keyboard; [<command>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/command) is deprecated.

Which HTML tag should I use for command line input?

Comment: It is code, so wouldn't using `<code>` tags be the proper semantic element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML spec has a perfect example that shows the use of `<pre>` in conjunction with `<kbd>` and `<samp>` (and some syntax highlighting-specific `<span>`s) to mark up a command line sample:

> This second example shows a block of sample output from a console program. Nested `samp` and `kbd` elements allow for the styling of specific elements of the sample output using a style sheet. There's also a few parts of the `samp` that are annotated with even more detailed markup, to enable very precise styling. To achieve this, `span` elements are used.
>
> ```html
> <pre><samp><span class="prompt">jdoe@mowmow:~$</span> <kbd>ssh demo.example.com</kbd>
> Last login: Tue Apr 12 09:10:17 2005 from mowmow.example.com on pts/1
> Linux demo 2.6.10-grsec+gg3+e+fhs6b+nfs+gr0501+++p3+c4a+gr2b-reslog-v6.189 #1 SMP Tue Feb 1 11:22:36 PST 2005 i686 unknown
>
> <span class="prompt">jdoe@demo:~$</span> <span class="cursor">_</span></samp></pre>
> ```

This example can be found [under the definition of `<samp>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-samp-element).

You don't need the `<span>`s, of course; those are just for syntax highlighting effects, and `<span>` itself, like `<div>`, does not carry any semantics whatsoever. In other words, the semantics of this example are identical with or without the `<span>`s.

There is nothing wrong with using `<code>` instead; it's really up to you. But if you want to follow a reference, then the spec provides one and I recommend it all the same.

Comment: Since the spec has a specific usage of `kbd` on the command input, I'm inclided to use kbd. `code` is too general in my opinion.

Comment: @Gqqnbig: Good call. Keep in mind that the examples in the spec, unlike the rest of the text, are not prescriptive so you can always choose to use something else if you ever find yourself disagreeing with the examples, at your own discretion. But they're a good reference nevertheless.

Comment: I revisited this question. Long ago I switched to use https://highlightjs.org/ and mark the code block as console or shell session. The library will highlight input and output separately.

Answer (score 0):

`<pre>` for blocks of code, `<code>` for fragments.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#elementdef-pre